# Getting Object Velocity in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to ask how I can get an objects velocity in three.js?

I've looked at [Object3D](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D) but nothing points to velocity.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> I've looked at Object3D but nothing points to velocity.

`three.js` does not support the concept of velocity or speed. If you need support for `velocity` (e.g. in context of game development), you have to implement the respective logic in your application.

`three.js R110`